# How to get rid of the default field markup

Tags: theming, forms

I need to customize registration form fields. Drupal generates form fields like this:

```
<div>
 <label>Name</label>
 <input type="text">
</div>
```

but I need to leave just `<input>` and be able to add some other tags around it.

For example:

```
<ul>
<li><span>Name</span><input type="text" /></li>
</ul>
```

It seems to be a common problem as the default html fields markup don't always what needs to be applied in particular html templates.

What is the best approach to this?

Answer (score 2):

As with pretty much everything like this in Drupal, the answer lies in overriding theme functions/templates.

That markup is added by the [`theme_form_element()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/theme_form_element/7) function; to override the output for that function simply add a function like this to your theme:

```
function THEMENAME_form_element($vars) {
  // ...
}
```

And change what you need to from the original function (e.g. replace `<div>` with `<ul>` if that's what you need). You might also need to override some of the individual element templates (depending on exactly what you want to do).

Some examples of those:

- [`theme_textfield()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/theme_textfield/7)
- [`theme_select()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/theme_select/7)
- [`theme_checkbox()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/theme_checkbox/7)